# Google Sheets Filter View Question

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

I am trying to create a filter to sort some data and all the sudden my usual method isn't working.

In column B I have set the filter to values W and G and then when I go to set the same values in column C the value G doesn't come up as an option to select,  but W does.

I am trying to find everyone in my list who has the values W and G.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The application of your Col-B filter list is ruling out options before you even set your Col-C filter list. In other words, it seems that any time G appears in Col C, neither G nor W appears in Col-B.

You will not be able to set to separate filters this way for the reason I've stated. You'll need to approach it a different way.

First, reset the Col-B and Col-C lists by clicking "Select all" for those lists, so that every option has a checkmark.

Then, apply a custom rule to Col A:

1.) Click to adjust the Col-A filter rule.

2.) Click "Filter by condition" and choose "Custom formula is" from the dropdown.

3.) In the custom formula field, enter this formula: `=REGEXMATCH($B2&$C2,"G|W")`